# React native--Unable to get unique value with unique Id from multiple TextInput in a loop

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, npmjs

`chargeTypeModelArrDly` is my Array in React js, which will iterate for the 6 time and create 6 textfield. I am unable to get unique value with unique Id which will help me to do calculation in `onEndEditing(e)` with unique `Id`.
please find the code below:

```
 _.each(this.props.chargeTypeModelArrDly,(chargeTypeModelArrDly,index))=>    
    {  <ListItem avatar key={index}>
          <TextInput 
                style={{width:50,height: 40, borderColor:'gray',borderWidth: 1}}
                defaultValue ={"0"}
                onEndEditing={(e) => this.onEndEditing(e) }
                keyboardType={'numeric'}
              />  
        </ListItem>
    }
```

Comment: cant you use index?

Comment: Can you explain why do you need this Id ? Does `chargeTypeModelArrDly`contain an id ? Do you want a `ref` to `TextInput` or do you want to identify the call of `onEndEditing()` ?

Comment: I try this code without Id but due to loop when I am giving value to the any of the text field inside loop It get override on all the text field inside loop,so I am unable get different value for the different text field .How do I get ref for the different text field,so I can get Value by it's ref for further calculation in function.

Comment: Yes,I can use Index

Comment: But the problem is I want to do further calculation in onEndEditing() function,where I cant get this index